# Why am I getting _parse_usage error on function invocation in bash?

Tags: command-line, bash, auto-completion, functions

So I was getting the following error:

```
bash: _parse_usage: line 16: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: _parse_usage: line 16: ` -?(\[)+([a-zA-Z0-9?]))'
bash: error importing function definition for `_parse_usage'
bash: _longopt: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: _longopt: line 14: ` --+([-a-z0-9_]))'
bash: error importing function definition for `_longopt'
```

Apparently only on function invocations.

Answer (score 6):

It turns out that the error comes from `bash-completion` package (`apt install bash-completion`). Reinstalling it had no effect, so it was not corrupted. After some trial and error I traced the trigger of this error to an innocent looking line

```
set -a
```

in a file sourced from .bashrc

Exporting all new variables in .bashrc is therefore not a good idea, unless you turn the option off again using

```
set +a
```

Comment: Other things that are not a good idea with bash-completion: [`shopt -s nullglob`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/276930/70524)

Comment: after squandering an hr on this, I added the following to the end of my bashrc (maybe will add to my prompt code instead)  `if set | grep -q allexport; then printf 'There is a set -a in a script somewhere'; fi`